# Nextjs Sitemap removing /en/ for all web links generated after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sitemap, strapi

I am using **Strapi**, it is pulled in JSON format.

Example of what a regular website link looks like:
https:/ /www.some-site.com/some-link

What happens to my links after post build is done on my Nextjs project:

```
<url><loc>https://website-name.com/en/something-links</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.7</priority><lastmod>2021-10-12T05:43:36.829Z</lastmod></url>
```

Now if you'll notice, the language (/en/) shows up on the link.
I have created a next-sitemap.js file to try and remove this issue but it is not working.

**Here is what the code in next-sitemap.js looks like:**

**next-sitemap.js**

```
const defaultRegion = 'us';
module.exports = {
  siteUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL,
  generateRobotsTxt: false,
  sitemapSize: 7000,
  transform: async (config, path) => {
    const defaultLocalePath = `/${defaultRegion}/`;
    let transformedPath = path;

    if (path.substring(0, defaultLocalePath.length) === defaultLocalePath) {
      transformedPath = path.substring(defaultLocalePath.length, path.length);
    }

    return {
      loc: transformedPath,
      changefreq: config.changefreq,
      priority: config.priority,
      lastmod: config.autoLastmod ? new Date().toISOString() : undefined,
      alternateRefs: config.alternateRefs ?? [],
    };
  },
};
```

I have over 200+ links and pages on my website.

**I am receiving an error in the first line itself**

Comment: Have you tried `path.replace(/en\//, "")`?

Comment: Added the below code:
module.exports = {
  siteUrl: 'https://straive.com',
  generateRobotsTxt: false, // (optional)
  sitemapSize: 7000,
  // ...other options
  // exclude: ['/en/'],
  transform: async (config, path) => {
  // console.log(path);
  // path.replace(/en\/(.*)/, "/$1")
  path.replace(/en\//, "")
  return {
    loc: path, // => this will be exported as http(s)://<config.siteUrl>/<path>
  }
}
}
Received a Error code, 800A03EA

Comment: `path.replace` will _not_ modify `path`, it returns the modified string instead. That error code doesn't tell me much, why is it erroring?

Comment: I do not understand why it is giving an error. I checked it online it's nowhere to be found. Do you know how to generate a sitemap through code and then be able to modify it?

Comment: @juliomalves can you please check the code above again, I have edited the code. I found this code here: https://github.com/iamvishnusankar/next-sitemap/issues/134                              But the error is now with the first line itself. I am unable to figure out why the first line first character be giving such an error, and why does it work for the other people who suggested this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of internationalization(also called i18n) in Next.js.

For removing /en/ from all links of your sitemap disable i18n & localization.

Go to the root directory of your nextjs project there you find a file "next.config.js" with code something like this

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en"],
    defaultLocale: "en"
  },
  env: {
    siteUrl: process.env.SITE_URL
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Just remove the i18n key value pair to disable localization like this.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    siteUrl: process.env.SITE_URL
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Now the dynamic next-sitemap will not generate the /en/ links.

I found this solution here [Tundla Developers](https://www.tundladevelopers.com/blog/nextjs-sitemap-removing-en-from-all-links)